# BLE Peripheral delegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I recently upgraded from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and iOS 10.3.3 to iOS 11.1.

I'm developing an application that uses BLE to communicate bi-directionally. The workflow is as follows:

1. PERIPHERAL - Advertise Identity
2. CENTRAL - Receive Identity (process it...)
3. CENTRAL - Respond to peripheral
4. PERIPHERAL - Receive response from central
5. Done

My code was working perfectly before the update but now it's not. At the end of step 4, I execute the following line:

```
peripheral.writeValue(encryptedData!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

This should call the following delegate method but it doesn't:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        print("Did Write")
        print("Error=\(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

It should also (and was calling) the following delegate method on the PERIPHERAL device but it doesn't:

```
public func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        print("did receive write request")
}
```

The service and characteristic are set as follows :

```
let prefs = Preferences()
            let strServiceUUID = prefs.GetString(key: Preferences.PREF_IDENTITY_SERVICE_UUID, defaultVal: "")!
            let strCharacteristicUUID = prefs.GetString(key: Preferences.PREF_IDENTITY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, defaultVal: "")!
            print("ServiceUUID=\(strServiceUUID)")
            print("CharacteristicUUID=\(strCharacteristicUUID)")
            mServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: strServiceUUID)
            mCharacterUUID = CBUUID(string: strCharacteristicUUID)
            mCBBluetoothServices = CBMutableService(type: mServiceUUID, primary: true)
            
            //lets configure the data we want to advertise for
            var characteristics : [CBCharacteristic] = []
            
            //let strData : String = "933911"
            //let data = strData.data(using: .utf8)
            let cbProperties: CBCharacteristicProperties = [.read, .write, .notify]
            let cbPermissions: CBAttributePermissions = [.readable, .writeable]
            mIdentityObjectCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: mCharacterUUID,
                                                                    properties: cbProperties,
                                                                    value: nil,
                                                                    permissions: cbPermissions)
            
            
            characteristics.append(mIdentityObjectCharacteristic)
            mCBBluetoothServices.characteristics = characteristics
            mCBPeripheralManager.add(mCBBluetoothServices)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why upgrading the OS and Swift versions broke your code, however, it looks to me like you may be using the wrong delegate method?

Try using this

```
func peripheral(CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

instead of this

```
func peripheral(CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?)
```

Comment: I changed it the correct delegate method but it still doesn't trap when I call peripheral.writeValue(encryptedData!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse).

Comment: That's unfortunate. Are you making sure that you actually are connected, have all the permissions, BLE is enabled etc.? I have had some issues with BLE connectivity after upgrading to iOS myself, in particular for old phones such as iPhone 5s. If you post some more of the code I can compare and see if we are seeing the samme issues.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

For any kind of update characteristic (ex. read/write characteristic), then the `didUpdateValueFor` delegate will be called.

So, first check in the following delegate methods.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    
    print("didUpdateValueForChar", characteristic)
    
    if let error1 = error{
        
        alertMSG(titleString: "Error", subTitleString: "Found error while read characteristic data, Plase try again", buttonTitle: "OK")
        
        print(error1)
    }
    else{
        
        print("Update Characteristic: ", characteristic)
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    
    print("Write Characteristic :", characteristic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
iOS 13

Some things to check:

1. Make sure to set the peripheral's `delegate` to whichever controller is conforming to the `CBPeripheralDelegate` protocol (this should also be the same controller that needs to implement the `peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)` method).
2. Make sure you are not specifying a [`.withoutResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicwritetype/withoutresponse) write type.
3. As mentioned by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47346931/2745495), there are two very similar delegate methods that have the signature `peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)`. Make sure you are implementing the correct one.

   - When writing to a **characteristic**:

     - [`writeValue(_:for:type:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue):

       ```
       func writeValue(_ data: Data, 
                       for characteristic: CBCharacteristic, 
                       type: CBCharacteristicWriteType)
       ```
     - [`peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral)

       ```
       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                       didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, 
                       error: Error?)
       ```
   - When writing to a **descriptor**:

     - [`writeValue(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1519107-writevalue)

       ```
       func writeValue(_ data: Data, 
                       for descriptor: CBDescriptor)
       ```
     - [`peripheral(_:didWriteValueFor:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1519062-peripheral)

       ```
       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                       didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, 
                       error: Error?)
       ```

It is easy to confuse the 2 sets of write and delegate methods.

Since you are using:

> ```
> peripheral.writeValue(encryptedData!, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
> ```

The code for the write and delegate pair should be something like this:

```
class BluetoothController: CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    ...
   
    func writeSomething(to characteristic: CBCharacteristic, of peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        let something = "1234"
        
        NSLog("Writing \(something) to \(characteristic.uuid.uuidString)")
        
        peripheral.delegate = self  // <===== You may have forgotten this?
        peripheral.writeValue(something.data(using: .utf8)!,
                              for: characteristic,
                              type: .withResponse)
    }

    ...

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("Write error: \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            NSLog("Wrote value to \(characteristic.uuid.uuidString)")
        }
    }
}
```